# How to protect an USB flash drive against writing?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Flash drives are Readable and Writable. If I mark all files in them as Read-Only the user can delete all files without seeing no warning.

How to mark the whole drive as Read-Only?

Comment: You could try for a [hardware solution](http://superuser.com/questions/302576/usb-hardware-vs-software-write-lock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the drive is NTFS formatted, you open the properties window in the files in question, head to the Security tab, and disable write permissions for users other than yourself.

Comment: This solution will also work with Mac OS X as Macs can read NTFS partitions but can't write to them.

Comment: But linux users won't respect such restrictions, right?

Comment: @user53850 I'm not entirely sure. I believe you can change the permissions under Linux, but I will have to check.

Comment: I promised to follow up, so I checked renaming a file within a password-protected Windows user profile under Ubuntu 10.10. Sure enough, Linux has no problems modifying it. I suppose there's not a cross-platform fix. Perhaps you should consider using a optical medium or placing the files within a TrueCrypt volume where write-access is password protected (though this requires software to be installed for each client).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of disabling write access for all drives connected to the current Windows instance:

1. Go to Start -> Run -> Type regedit and hit Enter or click on the OK button.
   Browse to:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
2. Create a new key called StorageDevicePolicies
   Right click on the Control, select New -> Key and type in StorageDevicePolicies
3. Create a DWORD called WriteProtect under StorageDevicePolicies that you created in step 2 and set the value to 1.

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2006/05/07/disable-write-access-to-removable-storage-devices/

Comment: Take note that this only works on the machine the USB drive is plugged into.